# Directory not there after creation

Tags: permissions, chmod, plex

I'm getting my feet wet in linux and command line starting with Ubuntu Server 16.04 on my media server. I'm having an issue where I create a directory and then it's not there I think.

This is what has happened:

```
victormonopoly@beepboopblop:~$ mkdir -p /media/plex
victormonopoly@beepboopblop:~$ service smbd restart
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'smbd.service'.
Authenticating as: victormonopoly,,, (victormonopoly)
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
victormonopoly@beepboopblop:~$ ls -l /media
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  2 13:59 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  4 21:10 plex
victorhooper@turdsandwich:~$ chmod -R 0755 plex/
chmod: cannot access 'plex/': No such file or directory
```

Wat am i doing wrong?

Comment: it should be `chmod -R 0755 /media/plex/`...unless you are inside `/media` then it can be `chmod -R 0755 plex/`...

Comment: Just an FYI to the OP: The hostname without a full domain doesn't really reveal anything; if you need to remove it from posts suggest edits and explain in the edit comment why the edit should be approved.  (There's no need to moderator-flag for that)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access that folder wrongly from `/home` which I see from your console address `victorhooper@turdsandwich:~$`.

The command should be: `chmod -R 0755 /media/plex/` and not `chmod -R 0755 plex/`. To Run the code as you have it, then:

1. Change into the media directory: `cd /media`
2. Then change permissions: `chmod -R 0755 plex/`

And normally you should be adding `sudo` to any operations in the `/`(root) directory where we have `/media`. So in case these don't work add `sudo` before each of these commands, but of course you might have disabled `sudo password requests` in the `/etc/sudoers` file. Assuming you have.